# Macro as an argument to a macro in C

Tags: c, macros

I want to know which macro gets replaced first in the following code

```
#define A 100
#define B 200
#define C(A,B) A+B
```

here when we use C, then evaluation will be from left to right or right to left. That is B gets the value first or A gets the value first

i gave this example just to make things look simple, may be i was wrong. the actual thing i want to ask is, if A and B also take arguments and have the scope of expansion, then which one would expand first

Comment: Just use macros for simple things - use the compiler for more complex things. It has type safety for one. Try to avoid macros

Comment: I *can't* be the only one that is staring at this thinking both the A and B macros are irrelevant. (not that I live and die in a preprocessor world, but still...)

Comment: There is nothing to be replaced, since you don't evaluate anything.

Comment: @WhozCraig - you are not the only one

Comment: `A` and `B` in the function-like macro `C` are **macro arguments**. They don't have anything to do with the `A` and `B` defines.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean. There's never a point where you can "see" half a result of the preprocessor; the entire input file is preprocessed, then handed over to the compiler.

I think that the names for the macro arguments will never also be replaced as if they were stand-alone symbols.

I tried it, and this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 100
#define B 200
#define C(A, B) A + B

int main(void) {
  printf("A=%d\nB=%d\nC(1,2)=%d\n", A, B, C(1,2));
  return 0;
}
```

prints

```
A=100
B=200
C(1,2)=3
```

So, `C(1,2)` expands to `1 + 2`, the definitions of `A` and `B` don't matter.

Of course I must say that I find the above *very bad practice*, since it's quite confusing. Never use all-caps names for macro arguments, since macros and preprocessor symbols tend to use such names.

Comment: +1 The closing paragraph in this should taught until recitation from a broken slumber is achieved.

Comment: I don't think that this is "bad" practice, or say worse than have any function or macro parameter named the same as another symbol. Has nothing to do with all caps names.

Comment: i gave this example just to make things look simple, may be i was wrong. the actual thing i want to ask is, if A and B also take arguments and have the scope of expansion, then which one would expand first

Comment: @kharevbv I think you maybe should post a new question, that really contains what you want to ask.

Comment: @kharevbv, pretty sure the order of evaluation is undefined. I don't have the sources to back me up right now but I'm pretty sure it's true.